# Localhost works but Computer Name does not

Tags: iis-7, firewall

When I'm trying to connect to my iis with localhost, everything works fine. When I'm trying to connect with the name of my computer instead of localhost, it doesn't work.

I've found that turning off windows firewall resolves the problem, but I would like to turn on Windows Firewall. So, which program or port should be allowed through the Windows Firewall to make it work?

Comment: check your firewall logs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you ping to the name of your computer which ip address do you see in the results? Is that the ip address of your network connection?
If that is the case, then you probably have to open up port 80 on your windows firewall. (I assume the site(s) on your IIS are running on port 80.) The firewall has to allow incoming traffic on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Firewall can not get out to your DNS to resolve your computer name back to 127.0.0.1

You can also put the computer name in the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host file along with the 127.0.0.1 address.

Comment: I've just installed Windows7. In Vista I never had to edit the host file, so there must be another way.

Comment: Windows7 has incomming and outgoing firewall, so you outgoing request might be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Very old post, I know. But for the sake of history and knowledge; Chances are you are using a proxy, in this case you need to add exception for your computer name in the your browser.

Comment: Helped me. Automatic proxy settings caused the problem in my case, though that is not what topic starter asked.

Answer (score 0):

1. open notepad
2. copy this below line:

   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   ```
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters]

   "NodeType"=-
   "DhcpNodeType"=-
   ```
3. save as "NETFIX.REG"
4. paste to your desktop.
5. double click.
6. restart.

Comment: You going to explain what this does, or just expect people to copy and paste random code into their computers?

Answer (score 0):

I was using a proxy and getting the same error in my Windows machine, until I did the following:

- Opened Internet Explorer
- Opened *Internet Options -> Connections (tab) -> LAN Settings*
- Check the **"Bypass proxy server for local addresses"** checkbox

Reloaded the local website with the computer name in the url, and voila!  Success!

Answer (score 0):

I observed this problem - the PC's IP address not getting resolved in a web browser, but the "localhost" based URL does get resolved - if you have the firewall on your PC invoked (via the AVG Antivirus UI, for example).

When I turned off the firewall in AVG, the IP address of the PC was getting resolved in the web browser.